# semaphore_wait_signal_trap deadlock in _class_initialize in iOS application

Tags: objective-c, ios, deadlock, semaphore

One of my entity managed objects need to setup a runtime-only tree-like structure where nodes are subclasses of `NSObject` (they are not managed object).

I setup that structure (and thus allocates a bunch of those nodes) in two places:

- when creating a new such managed object: everything is working fine.
- when reading back an existing managed object, in its `awakeFromFetch` method.

That's where I have my problem: the call to `Node *newNode = [Node alloc];` never returns. I can break using the debugger, and the code is stuck in `semaphore_wait_signal_trap`. Here is the full call stack:

```
#0  0x937ac0e2 in semaphore_wait_signal_trap ()
#1  0x937b1be6 in pthread_mutex_lock ()
#2  0x01881c73 in _class_initialize ()
#3  0x0188973f in prepareForMethodLookup ()
#4  0x01880069 in lookUpMethod ()
#5  0x018801d6 in _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache ()
#6  0x018930e3 in objc_msgSend ()
#7  0x000957d8 in -[MyEntity awakeFromFetch] at MyEntity:114
```

So it seems my Node class fails to initialize. Indeed, this is the very first use of the Node class in this session. To check that, I inserted a spurious allocation of a single `Node` at application startup time. That calls succeeds, and now the above problem disappears.

However, I am not satisfied, for two reasons:

1- I still don't understand why allocating a `Node` for the first time in `awakeFromFetch` fails. And I don't consider a bug fixed if I don't understand why it occurred and why the fix is an actual fix.

2- The application now crashes slightly later when using *another* class for the first time, this time not in any `awakeFromFetch`.

So clearly my problem is not related to `awakeFromFetch` nor Core Data. Somehow, my Objective-C runtime is misbehaving, I don't know why.

Simple question: what could lead `_class_initialize` to p-thread deadlock?

Indeed googling for `semaphore_wait_signal_trap` yields many hits, all related to pthreads, few related to iOS/Objective-C/Cocoa.

Note that I don't use threads at all here.

I'm puzzled. Any idea how to debug this?

Edit: the source line that never returns was:

```
Node *newNode = [[Node alloc] init];
```

To find out what's going on, I split it in two:

```
Node *newNode = [Node alloc];
newNode = [newNode init];
```

The problems occurs on the first of those two lines.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but I note 2 things [1] No init after the alloc of the node (so the object call stack is not set up) and [2] the stack looks like the AwakeFromFetch method is not found.

Comment: `init` comes *after* `alloc`. Since `alloc` never returns*, `init` is not [yet] called. `awakeFromFetch` is in the call stack: it is currently executing. * Actually, `alloc` is not even ever called, since before a class can be used (eg allocated), it must be initialized, in the `_class_initialize` routine. This is the one that deadlocks, before `alloca is even called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I cleaned all my targets, and rebuilt. No improvement.
Then I deleted Xcode's Derived Data directory, and lo and behold, the problem went away.

The reasonable conclusion is to assume some glitch/but in Xcode 4.

I will not even try to account for all the lost hours.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's document about [-[NSManagedObject awakeFromFetch]](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/awakeFromFetch) said that:

> **Important**:  Subclasses must invoke super’s implementation before performing their own initialization.

Did you do that?

However, even if this solve your problem, I don't know why ;)

Comment: Yep I do it. The problem is not in *instance* initialization but in *class* initialization.